# Como alterar valor de input dentro div com javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, funções, input, div

Eu já ate consegui alterar um input dentro da div, mas quando tento alterar o input de outras div não consigo, já tentei diversas coisas e nada.

div1

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-3">
                        <div class="input-group number-spinner">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dir="dwn"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="0" style="max-width:50px;">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dir="up"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                            </span>                         
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

div2

```
<div class="md-form mb-5" style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: space-between;">
        <div id="number-spinner1" style="width: 45%;">
            <i class="fab fa-btc"></i>
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm-email">Price:</label>
            <input type="name" name="building_ppv" class="form-control validate" id="ppv" disabled>
        </div>
        <div id="number-spinner2" style="width: 45%;">
            <i class="fab fa-btc"></i>
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm-email">Total:</label>
            <input type="name" name="building_total" class="form-control validate" id="total" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
```

div 3

```
<?php echo form_open(site_url("account/buy_building/"), array("" => "")) ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="building_view" value="0" id="building_view">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-bordered" style="margin-top:20px"> <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Save</button>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Script

```
$(document).on('click', '.number-spinner button', function () {    
    var btn = $(this),
        oldValue = btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input').val().trim(),
        newVal = 0;

    if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
        newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 1;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('building_view').value = newVal;
    btn.closest('.number-spinner').find('input').val(newVal);

    var ppv = 0 , total = 0;

    if(newVal>9999){
        ppv = 50;
        total=newVal*ppv;       
    }else if(newVal>4999){
        ppv = 60;
        total=newVal*ppv;       
    }else if(newVal>999){
        ppv = 70;
        total=newVal*ppv;       
    }else if(newVal>499){
        ppv = 80;
        total=newVal*ppv;       
    }else if(newVal>99){
        ppv = 90;
        total=newVal*ppv;       
    }else if(newVal<=99){
        ppv = 100;
        total=newVal*ppv;       
    }

    document.getElementById('ppv').value = ppv;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
});
```

No caso não consigo alterar o input com id `ppv` e `total`

Edit#1: Não sei se tem alguma coisa a haver, mas essas divs estão dentro de um foreach (são criadas varias vezes), será q é o id? Se for como eu resolvo isso?

Edit#2: A única coisa q não entendo é q se for o id, queria saber como que o script consegue colocar o valor dentro do input da div1, mas não consegue colocar dentro da div2, e olha q já tentei muita coisa

Comment: Quando é que aparece a div3? ela já está na página ao mesmo tempo que as outras?

Comment: Kd o @Bacco pra fechar uma anomalia dessas?

Comment: sim, a div3 esta no mesmo foreach, é um botão que leva ate meu controller

Answer (score 0):

Eu testei o seu código. Se você retirar esta linha:

```
document.getElementById('building_view').value = newVal;
```

Os dois inputs que você quer alterar recebem os valores.

Isso ocorre porque o código está sendo bloqueado ao chegar neste ponto, já que nos HTMLs que você postou não existe nenhum elemento com o id "building_view"

Comment: Desculpa, esqueci de colocar essa outra parte do código html, essa linha ela tem função e funciona, e mesmo se eu tirar ainda não funciona